# How to sort an Eloquent subquery

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two tables conected: Team and member. The models are connected by a n:m relationship and in my team views I will make a foreach loop to get the members of said team like this:

```
@foreach( $team->teammember as $member )
    {{ $member->firstname }} {{ $member->lastname }}
@endforeach
```

So far everything is great and working, my issue is, how do I get the members list sorted by lastname? In my controller I'm not getting the members, since the connection is done via the model, I can only sort the teams but not the members.

Comment: Add a `ORDER BY` to the query.

Comment: How is your relationship defined in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you can do this:

```
@foreach( $team->teammember()->orderBy('last_name')->get() as $member )
    {{ $member->firstname }} {{ $member->lastname }}
@endforeach
```

However, might be best to abstract this into the Model or something if you plan on doing it alot.

Comment: This sounds about right but I will use this a lot certainly, how do I change it in the model? right now I have public function team(){return $this->belongsTo('Team', 'team_id');} on Teammember model and hasMany on the Team model

Comment: You can create a new method in your Team model and then simply do;

`function teamMembersLastName()`
`{`
`return $this->teammember()->orderBy('last_name')->get()`
`}`

Answer (score 5):

If you ALWAYS want it sorted by lastname you can also add the sortBy call directly in the relationship function on the model.

```
    public function teammember() {
    return this->hasMany('Teammember')->orderBy('last_name');
    }
```

I prefer a separate method in this case as suggested by Darren Taylor to maintain flexibility, but it's nice to know you can chain to the relationship functions directly as well.

Comment: Superb approach !

Comment: Is it not weird that the name of the function is teammember rather than teammembers? It's a one-to-many relationship.