# Laravel Eloquent: How to order results of related models?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a model called **School** and it has many **Students** .

Here is the code in my model:

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Student');
}
```

I am getting all the students with this code in my controller:

```
$school = School::find($schoolId);
```

and in the view:

```
@foreach ($school->students as $student)
```

Now I want to order the **Students** by some field in the `students` table. How can I do that?

Comment: @JaredFarrish orderBy there would affect query on the `schools` table, not `students`, and obviously would throw an error, unless you join the tables.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You have a few ways of achieving this:

```
// when eager loading
$school = School::with(['students' => function ($q) {
  $q->orderBy('whateverField', 'asc/desc');
}])->find($schoolId);

// when lazy loading
$school = School::find($schoolId);
$school->load(['students' => function ($q) {
  $q->orderBy('whateverField', 'asc/desc');
}]);

// or on the collection
$school = School::find($schoolId);
// asc
$school->students->sortBy('whateverProperty');
// desc
$school->students->sortByDesc('whateverProperty');


// or querying students directly
$students = Student::whereHas('school', function ($q) use ($schoolId) {
  $q->where('id', $schoolId);
})->orderBy('whateverField')->get();
```

Comment: How to sort collections by multiple properties of the model? For example, I want to sort by class and then by their name. `$school->students->sortBy('whateverProperty')->sortBy('anotherProperty');` does not work. It only sorts the collection by 'anotherProperty'.

Comment: Here is a solution which works. It uses the closure. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25451441/225790

Comment: Yes, Mark Baker's linked solution is neat. Another solution would be `usort`.

Comment: @SajeebAhamed `xToOne` doesn't make sense to sort related models, so what is your question actually?

Comment: sortBy is perfect for me, still didn't need to use join... the only thing that I'm worried about is I'm doing sortBy in the views at the foreach

Comment: SortBy has saved me! I have it inside a foreach, the use is as classic SQL:  @foreach ($carts->sortBy('attribute.product_id') as $cartItem) ... where 'attribute' is a hasOne Eloquent relation

Answer (score 43):

you can add orderBy to your relation, so the only thing you need to change is

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Student');
}
```

to

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Student')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. What if I want to orderBy 2 things in student, need to change the relationship.

Answer (score 10):

To answer the original question, the `students` dynamic property can also be accessed as a relationship method.

So you have this to fetch all students:

```
$students = $school->students;
```

Now as a relationship method, this is equivalent:

```
$students = $school->students()->get();
```

Given this, you can now add in some ordering:

```
$students = $school->students()->orderBy('students.last_name')->get();
```

Since eloquent will be performing a join, make sure to include the table name when referencing the column to order by.

You can also add this to your `students` method if you want to set a default order that `$school->students` will always return. Check out the documentation for `hasMany()` to see how this works.

Answer (score 4):

For Many to one relation I found one answer on:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/order-by-on-relationship

```
$order = 'desc';
$users = User::join('roles', 'users.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
  ->orderBy('roles.label', $order)
  ->select('users.*')
  ->paginate(10);
```

this can save day... of anyone

Answer (score 0):

You can use this like this:

```
$students = $school->students()->orderBy('id', 'desc');
```

You can also use

```
$students = $school->students()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```