# Eloquent Ordering Related Data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Eloquent Repository to get a 'menu' by ID, and return all the associated 'menuitems' along with it. This is working fine, but I am having an issue reordering the 'menuitems' by one of their fields. So I am currently doing:

```
$menu = $this->menuRepo->getById($id, 'menuitems');
```

which calls this function within the Eloquent Repo:

```
public function getById($id, $with = false)
{
    if ($with)
    {
        return $this->model->withTrashed()->with($with)->findOrFail($id);
    }

    return $this->model->withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
}
```

That function is being used throughout the system, so ideally I want to leave that as it is - or would need to change it so that it would not break in all the current usages. But even so, when I tried to add a

```
->orderBy('name')
```

within there it applies to 'menu' and not 'menuitems'.

Comment: duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent: How to order results of related models?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700529/laravel-eloquent-how-to-order-results-of-related-models#25701143)

Comment: Thanks, I did have a good search first but this question seemed to have slipped the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your with($with) needs to be rewritten, so that it uses relationship constraints:

```
...->with($with => function($query){
   $query->orderBy('name','asc');
})->...
```