# Laravel 5.4 order by related table after using `with` statement

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.4

This is my simple structure:

```
public class Post{
  public function user(){
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
}
```

This is how I query (the query has pagination):

```
$query = Post::query();
$query->with('user');
```

I want to sort by `user.name`.
Now, I know that I can go `$query->with('user',function(){...order by here});`
But I need a detached method that I can run later in the stack.

```
$query->user->orderBy('name');
$query->user()->orderBy('name');
```

This https://stackoverflow.com/a/38741988/936651 says that it is possible, but I get the error: `Undefined property/method: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$user`

Is there any way to sort by related table after using `with` statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because when you do `$query = Post::query();` it will return an instance of the Query Builder, so when you after do `$query->user()` it gives you an error because the Query Builder does not have the method `user()`, that method exists in your Post model.

I won't provide any code since you've mentioned you already know how to do the `with()` way..