# How to order results of related models in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three model `ProductCategory` ,`Product` and `ProductPrice` . My models are like this

**ProductCategory.php**

```
  public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product');
    }
  public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
    }
```

**And my Product model is like this**

```
 public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ProductCategory');
    }

    public function price(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductPrice');
    }
```

Now i want get all the product of a category and sort them by `name/price` as requested.  My query for this is

```
        $query = ProductCategory::with(['product'=>function($q){
          $q->whereHas('price',function ($q){
              $q->where('quantity','>',0);
              $q->where('status',1);
          });

        }])->whereHas('category',function ($q) use ($cat){
            $q->where('category_slug',$cat);
        });

switch ($request->get('sort')){
                case 'price':
             $query->product()->price()->orderBy('amount','asc');
                    break;
                case 'name':
                        $query->product()->orderBy('title','asc');
                    break;

            }
  $data['result']=$query->paginate(30)->toArray();
```

So i was expecting that this query will return me product from the category and will sort them by `price or name` as requested. But instead of that its giving me error saying

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::product()
```

I have followed these threads but no help

[Laravel orderBy on a relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143061/laravel-orderby-on-a-relationship)

[Laravel Eloquent: How to order results of related models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700529/laravel-eloquent-how-to-order-results-of-related-models)

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/order-by-on-relationship

And few more these are the one i found to be close to my problem. Can anyone please help me with the query Thanks

Comment: You need to either use `->first()` or `->get()` on the end of your database queries otherwise it'll fetch nothing.

Comment: i have that sorry i will update the question

Comment: add this line `$query = $query->first()` before switch statement

Comment: This is giving me result but not giving the data of relational tables. It giving data from ProductCategory model only

Comment: your data model seems a bit off. Why do you have a hasOne on Product to ProductCategory but the ProductCategory belongsTo Product and Category? I assume your ProductCategory table looks like this: `id`| `product_id` | `category_id` ? If that is the case, it would make sense to have `category_id` directly in products table

Comment: first of all you have four models

Comment: Product category table is like this `id`| `product_id` | `category_id` | `sub_category_id` | `sub_sub_category_id`

Comment: update your question by all tables data structure

Comment: `Category` and `Product` are models here, `ProductCategory` is not a model because it cannot possibly make any sense on its own. Make it a pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can not be solved this way as i found out. To solve this problem another approach is necessary .

This is how i did this.

```
$query = Product::with('sizes','images')->whereHas('productCategory',function ($q) use ($cat,$request,$cate){
            $q->whereHas('category',function ($q) use ($cat ,$request,$cate){
               $q->where('category_slug',$cat);

            });

        });
        $data['result']=$query->get()->toArray();
```

This can easily be sorted