# Laravel Relationship Order By

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, sql-order-by, laravel-5.7

I have two tables **bookings**,**units**,**categories**,**shifts**

**bookings**

*bookingId*
*unitId*
*date*
*status*
*categoryId*,
*shiftId*

I need ordering conditions like below.

```
$query = $query->orderBy('date','ASC');
$query = $query->orderBy('status','DESC');
$query = $query->orderBy('shiftId','ASC');
$query = $query->orderBy('unit.name', 'DESC');
$query = $query->orderBy('categoryId','ASC');
```

I have created shifts, categories, units relationship in Booking Model.

```
public function shift(){
  return $this->hasOne(Shift::class,'shiftId','shiftId');
}
public function unit(){
  return $this->hasOne(ClientUnit::class,'clientUnitId','unitId');
}
public function category(){
  return $this->hasOne(StaffCategory::class,'categoryId','categoryId');
}
```

But when I tried, the unit name 4th condition of orderBy is not working properly, all other order conditions are on **Bookings**  table and 4th condition is with the relation table.

How can I do it with only relationship. In this projects I am not used any Joins in this project and I will expect a solution without a Join to units table.

Thank You.

Comment: You can't do it without joins, because you have to fetch related `units` before you order by them - unless you just order by `unitId` instead - since that already exists on your table.

Comment: I cant do it with unitId, because my client need order by name

Comment: You can use laravel collection **sortBy** method for multiple sorting. [REF](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/11)

Comment: @Jishad Then again, you can't do it without joins or fetching the data first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700529/laravel-eloquent-how-to-order-results-of-related-models