# Sort eloquent model with relationships Laravel

Tags: laravel, sorting, eloquent

I have a model that I want to sort based on a relationship property.

1. **First model "DeviceType":**

```
public function make()
{
    return $this->hasMany(DeviceMake::class);
}
```

2. **Second model: "DeviceMake":**

```
public function type()
{
    return $this->hasOne(DeviceType::class, 'id', 'device_type_id');
}

public function model()
{
    return $this->hasMany(DeviceModel::class);
}
```

3. **Controller:**

```
$type = DeviceType::with(['make'])->where('id', '=', $device_type_id)->first();
```

4. Table name is `device_makes` and I want to sort it by `name`. How can I do this?

Comment: u can try this `$type = DeviceType::with(['make'])->where('id', '=', $device_type_id)->orderBy('name', 'desc')->first();`

Comment: @CamBoKiDz not working :(

Comment: Your relationship models should be plural if they return a relationship that could contain more than one item. `public function models()`, `public function makes()`, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent: How to order results of related models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700529/laravel-eloquent-how-to-order-results-of-related-models)

Comment: @miken32 no, It's not the answer

Answer (score 0):

And what about?

```
$type = DeviceType::with(['make' => function ($query) { 
    $query->orderBy('name', 'asc');
}])->where('id', '=', $device_type_id)->first();
```

Please note that first() will only return the first model that matches your query whereas get() will return all of them.

Maybe you could try this instead in your Model:

```
public function make() { 
    return $this->hasMany(DeviceMake::class)->orderBy('name', 'asc'); 
}
```