# Laravel 6 - Relation OrderBy another relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have a project where i can access to company name like this:

```
$user->atc_results->first()->atc_company->name;
```

i'm tryng to order my results orderBy company_name but it doesn't work.

```
public function atc_results()
{
   return $this->hasMany('Modules\Atc\Entities\AtcResult')->with("atc_company")->orderBy("atc_company.name","asc");
}
```

can you help me ?

Comment: atc_company is hasOne or belongsTo?

Comment: and what is your purpose for getting one row with ordering?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent: How to order results of related models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700529/laravel-eloquent-how-to-order-results-of-related-models)

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur yes atc_company is belongsTo

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the closure within the array when calling with() to add further query elements to your atc_company relation:

```
public function atc_results()
{
   return $this->hasMany('Modules\Atc\Entities\AtcResult')
            ->with(['atc_company' => function($q) {
                $q->orderBy('name', 'desc');
            }]);
}
```

Comment: did you replace desc with asc ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably going the other way around will work

```php
class AtcCompany extends Model
{
    public function atcResults()
    {
        //Asumption that relation is belongsTo
        //Check the foreign key and owner key as per db
        return $this->belongsTo(AtcResult::class);
    }
}

//Somewhere in some controller method
function atc_companies()
{
    //$results will still contain data for both AtcResult & AtcCompany
    $results = AtcCompany::with('atcResults')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
    
   
    return $results;
}
```