# Laravel foreach sort by, show specific records first

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a foreach loop and I want to sort the list by showing records where is_active is null first, then anything else after.

```
    @foreach ($registrations->sortBy('is_active') as $registration)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: do you want to show only is_active = null or do you want to orderBy is_active descending ?

Comment: i want to show the records where is_active null at the top. Then is is_active has a value, they are below the null records.

Comment: $registrations->orderByDesc('is_active')->orderByDesc(...) ->get() should do it

Comment: what is the second sort by for?

Comment: in case of same is_active ... if 2 records share 'is_active' (eg. null) then the second orderBy will be used

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the syntax for sorting an Eloquent collection by multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451019/what-is-the-syntax-for-sorting-an-eloquent-collection-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: @simonecosci thats not doing it. The is_active record is still bottom not top

Answer (score 2):

first of all make a query that returns records in ascending order according to `is_active` value( I'm assuming that **0 is for inactive and 1 is for active**)

Query should be:

```
$records=DB::table('table_name')->orderBy('is_active','asc')->all();
return view('viewblade')->with('records',$records);
```

now you can display data in viewblade like:

```
@foreach($records as $record){
   {{$record->fieldName}}
}
@endforeach
```

Comment: If this solution works or not depends on the database system being used. Not all DBMS are using the same default ordering and some even allow for special order treatment of `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way,

```
 // specify second_column that will be used if multiple null values found

 $registrations = $registrations->sortByDesc('second_column')->sortBy('is_active');

 @foreach ($registrations->all() as $registration)
```