# Laravel - Sort array by string value first and then date

Tags: laravel, sorting, collections

I need help to sort array by couple of logics

```php
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "status": "pending",
    "date": "2019-08-01"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "status": "delivered",
    "date": "2019-08-01"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "status": "pending",
    "date": "2019-08-03"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "status": "delivered",
    "date": "2019-08-03"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "status": "delivered",
    "date": "2019-08-02"
  }
]
```

what I want to do is to sort the array to status pending show first, and then sort it by the date descending

I already test to using sortByDesc from laravel collection but the array looks like sorted it by just 1 function

```php
$collection = $collection->sortByDesc('date')->sortByDesc(function ($row, $key) {
      if($row['status'] == 'pending'){
         return 1;
      }else{
         return 0;
      }
});
```

My expected final result look like this :

```php
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "status": "pending",
    "date": "2019-08-03"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "status": "pending",
    "date": "2019-08-01"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "status": "delivered",
    "date": "2019-08-03"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "status": "delivered",
    "date": "2019-08-02"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "status": "delivered",
    "date": "2019-08-01"
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the unexpected behaviour of your tested method result?

Comment: @TharakaDilshan its sorted by status only not the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few solutions:

1. Use a custom callback and return an array [source](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/11#issuecomment-398873250)

```
$products->sortBy(function($product) {
            return [$product->param1, $product->param2];
 });
```

> This will sort a collection by param2 first, and then by param1

2. Use a custom callback and return a composite property to sort on [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25451441/7528944)

```
$posts = $posts->sortBy(function($post) {
    return sprintf('%-12s%s', $post->column1, $post->column2);
});
```

3. Sort your array by column 1, then split it up by column 2 and then merge it again (untested).

```
$collection->sortByDesc('date');
$collection->groupBy('status');
$collection->keyBy('status');
```

EDIT: Also I'm not sure if `sortByDesc('date')` works with date strings.

Comment: thanks solution number 1 works, I barely know sortby can return array value

Answer (score 0):

Your expected result can be achieved like this.

```php
$sorted = $collection
              ->sortByDesc('date')
              ->sortBy(function ($item) {
                  return 'pending' == $item['status'] ? 0 : 1;
              })
              ->values();
```

Comment: I tried your method, but the result is only sorted by status, field date return unsorted like before..

Comment: I tested this one and I got your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise:

```
      $collection= $collection->sort(
        function ($a, $b) {
            if(($a->status== $b->status) &&($a->status== 'pending')){
                return ($a->date >= $b->date) ? -1 : 1;
            }elseif($a->status== 'pending' && ($a->status!= $b->status)){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return ($a->date <= $b->date) ? 1 : -1;
            }
        }
    );
    $collection= $collection->sortByDesc('status');
```