# Laravel: How can I join a related table to use orderBy correctly?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.4

Here is the query I am using to get results of a camp:

```
$camp = Camp::where('camps.id', $camp_id)
    ->with(['athletes' => function ($q) use ($camp_id) {
    $q->with(['kickoffs' => function ($q) use ($camp_id) {
        $q->where('camp_id', $camp_id);
        $q->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }]);
  $q->with(['kickoff_results' => function ($q) use ($camp_id) {
       $q->where('camp_id', $camp_id);
       $q->orderBy('score', 'desc');
   }]);
```

But the results are not getting ordered correctly. I have learned that I must [join the tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861186/eloquent-eager-load-order-by) so now my query looks like this:

```
$camp = Camp::where('camps.id', $camp_id)
    ->with(['athletes' => function ($q) use ($camp_id) {
    $q->with(['kickoffs' => function ($q) use ($camp_id) {
        $q->where('camp_id', $camp_id);
        $q->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }])->join('kickoff_results', 'athletes.id', '=', 'kickoff_results.athlete_id')
       ->orderBy('kickoff_results.score', 'desc');
```

But this seems to be returning me the same thing. I feel like my results are more accurate with my first query, but the ordering is incorrect.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Create foreign key in the secondary table
and join the table as follows:

```
DB::table('leads')->select('sec_tbname.sec_tbfk','sec_tbname.join_pm','prm_tbname.prm_tbpm')
            ->join('pm_tbname','sec_tbname.sec_tbfk','=','pm_tbname.id')
            ->get();
```