# Laravel Eloquent: Order results by eaged loaded model.property, and paginate the result

Tags: laravel, pagination, eloquent, eager-loading

Lets say I have three models: `Post`, `Category` and `Tag`.

The Post `belongsTo` Category and Category `hasMany` Post.

Theres `manyToMany` relation between `Tag` and `Category`.

I want to list my posts by Category name and paginate the results.

```
Post::with('category','category.tags')
  ->orderBy('category.name') //this is the bogus line
  ->paginate(10);
```

But this syntax doesn't work.

---

What I tried is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861186/eloquent-eager-load-order-by) as:

```
Post::select('categories.*')
  ->join('categories','posts.category_id','=','categories.id')
  ->orderBy('categories.name)
  ->paginate(10);
```

But then I lose the eager loaded data.

If I drop the `select()` clause then I get rubbish data as `categories.id` overwrites `posts.id`. See [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4962).

---

Is there any elegant way to solve this issue? <s>After spending hours on this I'm one step away from iterating through paginated posts and 'manually' loading the relations as:</s>

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
  $post->load('category','category.tags');
}
```

Not even sure if there's downside to this but it doesn't seem right. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

UPDATE on last step: Eager loading on paginated results won't work so if I go that road I'll need to implement even uglier fix.

Comment: Did you tried `Post::with('category','category.tags')->select('categories.*')
  ->join('categories','posts.category_id','=','categories.id')
  ->orderBy('categories.name)
  ->paginate(10);` ??

Comment: Yes, as soon as I add `select()` none of the data specified in the `with()` method is not returned. I do get `category` but it's an empty array.

Comment: the with wont work because `select('categories.*')` is wrong, you need the `posts` table fields instead. See my answer (updated now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use both `join` and `with`.

```
Post::select('posts.*') // select the posts table fields here, not categories
->with('category','category.tags')
->join('categories','posts.category_id','=','categories.id')
->orderBy('categories.name)
->paginate(10);
```

remember, the with clause does not alter your query. Only after the query is executed, it will collect the n+1 relations.

Your workaround indeed loses the eager loading benefits. But you can call `load(..)` on a collection/paginator (query result) as well, so calling `->paginate(10)->load('category','category.tags')` is equivalent to the query above.