# Ordering by count in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my Laravel application, I have implemented Tagging of articles and events. This is accomplished by having two tables: `tags` and `taggables`. In my tag controller, I have an index method that grabs all the tags, a count of the tags and the same logic to count used tags.

It looks like this:

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $tags = Tag::orderByDesc('name')->get();    
    $tagCount = count($tags);
    $usedTags = Tag::has('articles')->orHas('events')->orderBy('name')->get();
    $usedTagsCount = count($usedTags);

    return view('pages.tags.index', compact('tags', 'usedTags', 'tagCount', 'usedTagsCount'));
}
```

I pass all this data to my view which looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <!-- Search results -->
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="padded-content-box">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                            <h1 class="heading">Tags</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="padded-content-box">
                    <div class="header">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                                <h2 class="sub-heading">
                                    All Tags ({{ $tagCount }})
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="tag-row">
                            <div class="tag-words-list">
                                @foreach($tags as $tag)
                                    <a class="tag-word" title="{{ $tag->name }}" href="{{ URL::action('TagController@show', $tag->slug) }}">{{ $tag->name }}</a>
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="padded-content-box">
                    <div class="header">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                                <h2 class="sub-heading">
                                    Tags currently in use ({{ $usedTagsCount }})
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="content">
                        @foreach($usedTags as $tag)
                        <p>
                            <a class="tag-word" title="{{ $tag->name }}" href="{{ URL::action('TagController@show', $tag->slug) }}">{{ $tag->name }}</a> 
                            x {{  count($tag->articles) + count($tag->events) }}
                        </p>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, to show a count of tags used I just add the articles and events that have a given tag.

How would I count how many times each tag is used in both events and articles, then order them by the count. Essentially if a tag has been used the most it would be at the top of a list.

**Update**

As suggested I have changed my controller method to look like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $tags = Tag::orderBy('name')->get();

    $tagCount = count($tags);

    $usedTags = Tag::has('articles')->orHas('events')->withCount('articles', 'events')->orderByRaw('articles_count + events_count DESC')->orderBy('name')->get();

    $usedTagsCount = count($usedTags);

    return view('pages.tags.index', compact('tags', 'usedTags', 'tagCount', 'usedTagsCount'));
}
```

This ensures that the tags are in count and alphabetical order.

Then in my view I changed the count code to this:

```
<p>
    <a class="tag-word" title="{{ $tag->name }}" href="{{ URL::action('TagController@show', $tag->slug) }}">{{ $tag->name }}</a> x {{  $tag->articles_count + $tag->events_count }} 
</p>
```

This way I get to remove some minor logic from the view.

Comment: i didnt exactly understqnt your question but this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861186/eloquent-eager-load-order-by

Comment: Instead of `->get()` use `->count()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `withCount()`:

```
$tags = Tag::withCount('articles', 'events')
    ->orderByRaw('articles_count + events_count DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I really need to stop re-inventing and use what the docs provide, I'm just coding up what I think is the solution and then I will add it, incorporating your answer.

Comment: Would it be feasible to also have this in the Model so that I could make a tag usage attribute?

Comment: The `$tags` models get a `articles_count` attribute. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)