# Laravel Get Result Ordred By For an eager Loaded Relation

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have:

- 'cards' table
  -id
  -name
- 'card_categories' Table

  - id
  - card_id
  - category_id
- 'categories' Table

  - id
  - name
  - index

I'am Loading The Card then Eager load the Relation, what i would like to do is when doing this :

Card::with('ctrCategories.category').......;

I would like that all loaded category from categories will be sorted by Index just the categories.

I spent the hole day doing everything , but no solution:

I tried this:

$card  = Card::findOrFail($id);
       return $card->with('cardCategories')

```
   ->with('ctrCategories.category')
   ->with('ctrCategories.arguments')
   ->orderBy('ctrCategories.category.index')->get();
```

I also tried this approach:

```
$data = $this->card
->with([
    'roles' => function ($q) {
        $q->with(['tabs' => function ($q) {
            $q->with(['department' => function ($q) {
                $q->with(['panel' => function ($q) {
                    $q->orderBy('position', 'asc');
                }])->orderBy('position', 'asc');
            }])->orderBy('position', 'asc');
        }])->orderBy('position', 'asc');
    }
])
```

->findOrFail($id);

=====EDIT=====

I writed the SQL query and i got the result i want Now i want to transform it to Laravel Eloquent or DB query:

select `cards`.`id`,
`cards`.`name`,`categories`.`name`,`categories`.`id`,`categories`.`index`
from `cards`
inner join `card_categories` on `cards`.`id` = `card_categories`.`card_id` inner join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `card_categories`.`category_id`
where `cards`.`id` = 120
AND `cards`.`support_id`= `categories`.`support_id`
order by `categories`.`index` asc

any help ? I can't figure it out  after couple of hours of testing

Comment: You can pass a closure with the `orderBy` when you are eager loading the relation, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18862651/9193055).

Comment: Already tested that and same problem

Comment: try doing this in the Card Model file in the relation function `function cardCategeories(){ return $this->hasMany(cardCategeory::class)->orderBy('desc');}` i tried to do whereIn query in my project & it worked with me , this may work

Comment: @EslamElhakmey Hi, i want to sort the result of the loaded relation category not cardCategories, cardCategories is the Pivot table, so i did this:

public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Category::class, CardCategory::class);
    }

Comment: i meant trying to add whatever query you want to the relation, like this `function categories() { return $this->hasManyThrough(Category::class, CardCategory::class)->orderBy('position', 'asc'); }` try doing this, it may work

Comment: =====EDIT=====

I writed the SQL query and i got the result i want Now i want to transform it to Laravel Eloquent or DB query:

select cards.id, cards.name,categories.name,categories.id,categories.index from cards inner join card_categories on cards.id = card_categories.card_id inner join categories on categories.id = card_categories.category_id where cards.id = 120 AND cards.support_id= categories.support_id order by categories.index asc