# Problem with laravel relations and latest, paginate

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have some relations in my DB and heres the relatin i'm working with:

```php
$category = Category::with('article')
    ->where('slug', '=', $slug)
    ->latest()
    ->paginate(12);
```

the `articles` fetch and everything are ok, but latest method and paginate won't work!
it means the collection is ascending & not paginated.

any ideas? thanks.

Comment: By default `latest` uses `created_at` column name, if you want to use different column, pass it as 2nd parameter.

Comment: Define "won't work". is the sorting incorrect? Are you getting the wrong page? ...

Comment: @Jerodev means the collection isn't paginated and all rows will fetch in ascending mode, so latest and paginate won't return what i want.

Comment: Do you want to order by articale create date or by category create date? Becounse in your case `latest()` and `paginate()` relates to `Category model`.

Comment: @Jerodev om, that's the point i think. collection should order by the article model.

Comment: @Ar.Bazargani check this answer (very similar case): https://stackoverflow.com/a/18882219/5252403

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine for me as i have change acording to my models.

```
$category = Doctor::with('detail')
            ->where('name', 'like', '%a%')
            ->latest()
            ->paginate(12);
            dd($category);
```

It's output is here[image]