# Is there a way to select fields from an eager loaded table in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

So I have a couple of relational tables defined below

Parent DB:

```
public function backorderQuantities(){
        return $this->hasMany(BackorderQuantity::class, 'ITEMNMBR', 'ITEMNMBR')->where('SOPTYPE', 5);
    }
```

Relational DB:

```
 public function item(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class, 'ITEMNMBR', 'ITEMNMBR');
    }
```

And I am calling the relationship like so:

```
Item::has('backorderQuantities')
            ->select('ITEMNMBR',
                Item::raw("SUM(QTYONHND) as qty"),
                Item::raw("SUM(QTYONORD) as ordered"),
                Item::raw("SUM( ( CASE WHEN LOCNCODE LIKE 'IT-%' THEN QTYONHND END ) ) as transit"), 
            )
            ->where('PRIMVNDR', Auth::user()->vendor_id)
            ->groupBy('ITEMNMBR')
            ->orderBy($group['field'], $group['sort'])
        );
```

This works fine, but I need to select fields from within backorderQuantities as well so that I can sort by said fields. In other words I want to do something like this:

```
 Item::has('backorderQuantities')
            ->select('ITEMNMBR',
                Item::raw("SUM(QTYONHND) as qty"),
                Item::raw("SUM(QTYONORD) as ordered"),
                Item::raw("SUM( ( CASE WHEN LOCNCODE LIKE 'IT-%' THEN QTYONHND END ) ) as transit"),
                'backorderQuantities->QUANTITY'
            )
            ->where('PRIMVNDR', Auth::user()->vendor_id)
            ->groupBy('ITEMNMBR')
            ->orderBy('backorderQuantities->QUANTITY', $group['sort'])
```

But I hit an error like this:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'backorderQuantities'. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select [ITEMNMBR], SUM(QTYONHND) as qty, SUM(QTYONORD) as ordered, SUM( ( CASE WHEN LOCNCODE LIKE 'IT-%' THEN QTYONHND END ) ) as transit, json_value([backorderQuantities], '$."QUANTITY"') from [IV00102] where exists (select * from [SOP10200] where [IV00102].[ITEMNMBR] = [SOP10200].[ITEMNMBR] and [SOPTYPE] = 5) and [PRIMVNDR] = YHI group by [ITEMNMBR]) as [aggregate_table])

Probably because the table is still getting eager loaded at the time. Is there any way to do this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use **join** instead of eager loading.

Similar question already exists on the Laracasts forum:
[here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/order-by-on-relationship)

Comment: I'm fairly new/not great with SQL (primarily come from a mongoDB background) can you show me how the structure would look using my preexisting query with join instead?

Comment: I simplified my relational table to backorder and tried this `Item::join('backorders', 'items.ITEMNMBR', '=', 'backorders.ITEMNMBR')` , but I hit this error: `SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'backorders'. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from [IV00102] inner join [backorders] on [items].[ITEMNMBR] = [backorders].[ITEMNMBR])`

Answer (score 0):

you can select columns of eger loading by using **with** :

```
 Item::with('backorderQuantities:QUANTITY,...');
```

don't forgot pass forigen key of **backorderQuantities** table to selected columns

**Edit :**

for sorting by child column you should use join statement :

```
 Item::select('items.*')->leftJoin('items.ITEMNMBR','=','backorderQuantities.ITEMNMBR')->groupBy('backorderQuantities.ITEMNMBR')->orderBy('backorderQuantities.backorderQuantities')
```

Comment: How would I be able to sort orderby with that field within the same query though?

Comment: you would to order backorderQuantities or Item  table and wich column  you are using for sorting?

Comment: I need to be able to sort by `backorderQuantities:QUANTITY` as well as the various columns listed above from Item

Comment: in this case you should use sql join ..check update

Comment: no dice `SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'items.ITEMNMBR'. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select [items].* from [IV00102] left join [items].[ITEMNMBR] on [=] = [backorderQuantities].[ITEMNMBR] group by [backorderQuantities].[ITEMNMBR]) as [aggregate_table])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219627/discussion-between-brose-and-ahmed-atoui).