# Sort inside the with in laravel

Tags: laravel, sorting, eloquent

```
$posts =  PostUrl::with(['post' => function ($q) {
    $q->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}])
->where('category','like' ,'%'.$cat.'%')
->paginate(8);
```

How can I sort the result as per the created_at of the post inside?

When try to `->orderBy('post.created_at','DESC')` it show column not found.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861186/eloquent-eager-load-order-by)

Comment: https://reinink.ca/articles/ordering-database-queries-by-relationship-columns-in-laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add PostUrl models

```
public function post(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'postid')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}
```

Controller :

```
$posts =  PostUrl::with(['post'])->where('category','like' ,'%'.$cat.'%')->paginate(8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have established correctly in your PostUrl model the relationship with your Post model (if it is so called). You should have a function similar to the following in your model in order to with() method works correctly in the controller:

```
public function post(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'postid');
    }
```

This way there should be no problem for the orderBy clause to work properly.