# OrderBy Laravel Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to order listing_data based on listing_packages.order . Here is the query

```
ListingData::with(['listing_package'])->orderBy('listing_package.order','desc')->paginate(24);
```

I would like to order based on listing_package.order "DESCENDING"

However, it returns

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'listing_package.order' in 'order clause'

Here is the model ListingData.php

```
public function listing_package(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ListingPackage::class);
}
```

Here is the model for ListingPackage.php

```
public function listing_data(): HasMany {
    return $this->hasMany(ListingData::class);
}
```

Edit:

I also try this one

```
    $relations = [
        'district',
        'regency',
        'province',
        'category',
        'type',
        'rentType',
        'listing_package' => function ($q){
            $q->orderBy('order','DESC');
        },
    ];
    $listings = ListingData::with($relations)
    ->latest()
        ->paginate(24);
```

But the data is not sorted

Am I missing something here?

Comment: [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861186/eloquent-eager-load-order-by), a closure func on the with

Comment: Hi, I have updated using with but data is not sorted. Please check out my answer, is it correct way to do it anyway?

Comment: In my experience, you can't sort a Query (`ListingData`) by it's relationship (`ListingPackage`), since behind the scenes, Laravel uses subqueries to load the related data, not a `join`. You can use a manual subquery (like in your answer), or you can use a `join` and sort on that, like Muhammad's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found out two alternatives which is working. The first one is using join but seems bit complicated (messy). The second one is subquery in orderBy

```
ListingData::with($relations)
        ->orderBy(ListingPackage::select('order')->whereColumn('listing_data.listing_package_id','listing_packages.id'),'desc')
        ->latest()
            ->paginate(24);
```

Testing performance under 50k data, took 0.027 sec

[image]

I am still searching for the most effective way to do this. Will post it here. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this one maybe this will help you.

```
$listings = ListingData::with($relations)
    ->join('listing_packages', 'listing_datas.listing_package_id', '=', 'listing_packages.id')
    ->orderByDesc('listing_packages.order')
    ->latest()
    ->paginate(24);
```

Comment: I tried using join, when its sorted by latest its getting so slow. About 0.2 sec which subquery much faster. However, if we do not use latest(). Join is much faster than subquery. The usage would be depend in our needs.

FYI: I have indexed the created_at while using join then order by latest()